# Как собрать проект exe JavaFX в IntellIJ 2023

Tags: javafx, build

не судите строго, только постигаю азы сферы программирования. Дошел до момента когда нужно собрать рабочую программу для запуска в Windows. Саму программу собирал на JDK 11 Belsoft, и в IntellIJ запускается, однако она не дает скомпилировать ее, выдавая эту ошибку:
**Java FX Packager:
BUILD FAILED**
C:\Users\muh1\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2023.1\compile-server\viccam_base_eef2cf6a_temp_\build.xml:29: Error: Bundler "Windows Application Image" (windows.app) failed to produce a bundle.
и
**Java FX Packager: fx:deploy task has failed.**

Компиляцию делал как указанно везде на сайтах:

1. Создал артефакт JavaFX Application
2. Добавил в него с правой колонки все что входит в пакет
3. Указал основной класс и Notive bundle all
4. Build - Build Artifact
   и... ни чего не получилось

куда копать и где искать ответ? очень нужна помощь